# Can not execute a query in "gremlin" using Orientdb v-3.0.0

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I want to execute a query such as `g.v('#21:0')` using orientdb studio version 3.0.0. But when I execute this command, I get this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find a script executor
>   requester for language: gremlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinkerPop 3 has been removed from OrientDB as a dependency since version 3.0 however you can install it by:

```
git clone https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin
cd orientdb-gremlin
git checkout develop
mvn clean install
```

Check out the docs here for more info:

[OrientDB Docs | Apache TinkerPop 3](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/tinkerpop3/OrientDB-TinkerPop3.html#source-code-installation)